# Calculate the $n^{th}$ derivative of this functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the following function:
$$ f_1(x)=x^3e^x,\quad\quad f_2(x)=x^2(1+x)^n$$
How to calculate the $n^{th}$ derivative using the General Leibniz rule:
$$ (fg)^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x)$$

#### My work:

let $g(x)=x^3$ and $h(x)=e^x$
 and for $k\in\Bbb{N}^*$;
$$ g^{(k)}(x)=
\begin{cases}\frac{3!}{(3-k)!} x^{3-k}& k\leq 3\\
0 & k> 3\end{cases}$$
and, $$ h^{(k)}(x)=e^x$$
then, $$ f_1^{(n)}(x)=\begin{cases}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{3!}{(3-k)!} x^{3-k}e^x & n\leq 3 \\
\sum_{k=0}^{3}\binom{3}{k}\frac{3!}{(3-k)!} x^{3-k}e^x  & n>3
\end{cases}$$

The second function i couldn't do it since it involves the power of $n$ and i want to calculate the $n^{th}$ derivative.

Thanks you for your answers and hints.

Comment: Your result for $f_1$ is not correct, it does not simply become 0. Some of the terms become 0 but that is differemt.

Comment: For $f_2(x)$, it is probably easiest to expand the function using the binomial theorem. Differentiating a degree $n+2$ polynomial $n$ times should yield a degree $2$ polynomial (with coefficients dependent on $n$) as the answer.

Comment: For any $k$, can you compute the $k$th derivative of $f_2$? Do that, then choose $k = n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can only take $2$ derivatives of $x^2$, so you need to take $n-2,n-1,$ or $n$ of the second term.  So we have 
$$\left(x^2(1+x)^n\right)^{(n)}=x^2\left((1+x)^n\right)^{(n)}+2nx\left((1+x)^n\right)^{(n-1)}+2{n \choose 2}\left((1+x)^n\right)^{(n-2)}\\
=x^2n!+2nxn!(1+x)+2n(n-1)\frac {n!}2(1+x)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Lets focus on the more general case of $x^\alpha e^x$.

Assume that $D^nf(x)=f^{(n)}(x)$.
$$D^0x^\alpha=x^\alpha$$
$$D^1x^\alpha=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$$
$$D^2x^\alpha=\alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}$$
$$...$$
$$D^kx^\alpha=x^{\alpha-k}\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)\\=x^{\alpha-k}(\alpha-1+1)(\alpha-2+1)(\alpha-3+1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)$$
Note that if $\alpha$ is an natural number ($1,2,\dots$), we have that $k=\alpha+1$ is also a natural number, meaning that $D^kx^\alpha=0$. It then follows that $D^kx^\alpha=0$, provided that $k>\alpha$ is a natural number. This is the case because for such values of $k$,
$$\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)=0$$
My point is, it is sufficient to write 
$$D^kx^\alpha=x^{\alpha-k}\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)$$
because the $\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)$ bit automatically encodes the cases of $k\leq \alpha$, and $k>\alpha$. Also, this formula for $D^kx^\alpha$ works even if $\alpha$ is *not* a whole number.

You already know that $D^ke^x=e^x$, so we may conclude with 
$$D^n(x^\alpha e^x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}e^xx^{\alpha-k}\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)$$
We can simplify by noting that 
$${n\choose k}=\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{n-j+1}j$$
Then combining products:
$${n\choose k}\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)=\bigg(\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{n-j+1}j\bigg)\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)\bigg)$$
$${n\choose k}\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)=\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{(n-i+1)(\alpha-i+1)}{i}$$
$${n\choose k}\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha-i+1)=\frac1{k!}\prod_{i=1}^k(n-i+1)(\alpha-i+1)$$
Which gives our simplified result:
$$D^n(x^\alpha e^x)=e^x\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^{\alpha-k}}{k!}\prod_{i=1}^k(n-i+1)(\alpha-i+1)$$

---

If you are unfamiliar with $\prod$ notation, 
$$\prod_{i=1}^na_i=a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3\cdots a_n$$
$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i=a_1\cdot a_2\cdot a_3\cdots$$
It is exactly the multiplication version of $\sum$ notation.